# How to add product categories to each line_items woocomerce rest api

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

With the current Woocommerce documentation, am able to retrieve all orders from woocommerce on the website.

```
"line_items" => array:2 [▼
0 => array:14 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "name" => "Multi Tool"
  "product_id" => 227
  "variation_id" => 0
  "quantity" => 1
  "tax_class" => ""
  "subtotal" => "15.00"
  "subtotal_tax" => "0.00"
  "total" => "15.00"
  "total_tax" => "0.00"
  "taxes" => []
  "meta_data" => []
  "sku" => ""
  "price" => 15
]
1 => array:14 [▶]
```

Problem is, the api doesn't provide categories for each product, it only responds with just a product_ id under line_items. Is there away i could add a custom field under each product called categories with the category name for each product?

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the response of the Orders API using the below filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_shop_order_object', 
'custom_change_shop_order_response', 20, 3 );
function custom_change_shop_order_response( $response, $object, $request ) {
//here you can customize the product response of the order
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Mr. Ajay, in the add_filter you have provided. what does the 20, and 3 stand for. And secondly is there any resource on the internet where i can learn how to customize the woocommerce api.

Comment: 20 is the priority of this filter and yes 3 is the parameters of this filter.

Comment: 1st parameter $response where you can get the default response of the products using that you can customize the response.